# _CastError (type '_CompactIterable<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>' in type cast)

Tags: json, flutter, api, dart

**I want to deserialize JSON files using this model but this problem occurred. If I am wrong deserialize the file. What is the proper technique to deserialize the file and show the key name like (Thriller, Actions,..) in list-view and by clicking that listview It would display movies-name in grid-view.**

**This is a local json file structure**

```
{
  "Thriller": [
    {
      "Death Clique": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Q9lTjqQeBU&ab_channel=VMovies"
    },
    {
      "CID": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Q9lTjqQeBU&ab_channel=VMovies"
    },
    {
      "Wrong Turn": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9spc-dExLH0&ab_channel=SagarForever"
    },
    
  ],
  "Action Movie": [
    {
      "Nobody": "https://nobodymovie.com"
    },
    {
      "Tenet": "https://tenetmovie.com"
    },
    
  ],
  "Romantic Movie": [
    {
      "Titanic": "https://titanicmovie.com"
    },
    {
      "The Vow": "https://thevowmovie.com"
    },
    
  ]
}
```

**This is the model of the json file.**

```
class MovieCategories {
  final String? title;
  final List<Movie>? subServices;

  MovieCategories({ this.title, this.subServices});

  factory MovieCategories.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
     var list = json.values as List;
    List<Movie> imagesList = list.map((i) => Movie.fromJson(i)).toList();

    return MovieCategories(
      title: json.keys.toString(),
      subServices: imagesList,
    );
  }
}
class Movie {
  final String? title;
  final String? url;

  Movie({this.title, this.url});

  factory Movie.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson){
   return Movie(
     title:parsedJson.keys.toString(),
     url:parsedJson.values.toString()
   );
  }
}
```

**API call :**

```
class FetchData {
  static final List<MovieCategories> data = [];
  static Future<String> _loadAddressAsset() async {
    return await rootBundle.loadString('assets/json/movie-categories.json');
  }

  static Future<List<MovieCategories>> loadAddress() async {
    data.clear();
    final jsonAddress = await _loadAddressAsset();
    final jsonResponse = json.decode(jsonAddress);
    data.add(MovieCategories.fromJson(jsonResponse));
    print(data);
    return data;
  }
}
```

Comment: [`List.map`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.16.1/dart-core/Iterable/map.html) returns a lazy *`Iterable`*.  It is *not* a `List`, so you cannot just cast it to one.  If you want to create a `List` from it, `list.map(...).toList()`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this line:

```dart
var list = json.values as List;
```

`Map.values` isn't a `List`, it's an `Iterable`. If you want it as a list, you need to convert it:

```dart
var list = json.values.toList();
```